# Async WCF integration with NServiceBus

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, nservicebus

I am new to NServiceBus and am trying to do something that seems harder than it should be...so I am starting to wander if I am missing something about the nsb bigger picture.

Here is the scenario:

- Expose WCF endpoint to client from which they request a long-running operation.
- I'd like to map the inbound request to a NServiceBus Message.
- Publish the message to the bus for processing.
- Send a reply to the client acking that their request has been received and we will begin processing it.
- Bus works the message through a handler.
- When the work has been completed, call the client back on their "callback" endpoint (wcf) to give them the result of the long-running request that they made.

I welcome corrective criticisms, examples or links that may be of use. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which WCF bindings are you using?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure what difference that would make? I am not going to be able to use a wcf callback contract (I dont think). We'll be running IIS 7, so likely wsHttp.

Answer (score 2):

There is potential for you to do this via the NSB pipeline.  You can configure handlers to execute in the order you specify.  In your case this would be book-ended with the notifications.  Depending on the use case it may be better to forward the notifications to another endpoint that handles just those types of communications.  What you need to consider are the failure scenarios.  If the handler fails and the message gets retried, what will happen?

This is all predicated on the idea that you do not need to maintain state.  If you do, then you will want to look into using a [Saga](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/).  This will keep state around per long running transaction and give you some more features you may require, such as timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

According to the NServiceBus [website](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/nservicebus-and-wcf), you can expose your NSB endpoint as a WCF service:

> Interoperability
>
> You can expose your NServiceBus endpoints as WCF services with as
>   little as one line of code and the standard WCF configuration. All you
>   need to do is write an empty class that inherits from
>   NServiceBus.WcfService specifying the types of the request and the
>   response and NServiceBus does the rest as follows:
>
> `public class MyService : NServiceBus.WcfService<MyCommand, MyErrorCodes> { }`

I have done some work integrating legacy MSMQ clients with NServiceBus - it works but you have to make sure the message is constructed correctly.

Messages sent to an NServiceBus endpoint must be enclosed in a `<Messages/>` envelope and must have a namespace. For example:

```
<Messages xmlns="http://tempuri.net/MyNservicebusMessage">
  <MyNservicebusMessage body/> ...etc
</Messages>
```

Also, if you want to use NServiceBus auditing you have to ensure the MSMQ "Response Queue" message header has a value, although I don't think the value matters.

Comment: This solution is for a synchronous scenario, though. The key point of my scenario is that I have a long running task and will need to call the client back after the results are obtained.

Answer (score 1):

A long running process can be either synchronous or asynchronous. It can't be both.

You can use NServiceBus for asynchronous processing of the long running task and generating of your progress information. Adam mentions the sagas. You can use a saga to keep track of progress. It will also help you with dividing you process into more granular tasks and give things like automatic retries that deal with transient failures for free.

However, you will have to use another mechanism to send the progress information back to the user. Periodic polling, long polling, hidden iframe, websockets, whatever - have a look at ideas exposed by SignalR. There's a nice video [here](http://vimeo.com/43659069) that talks about sending notifications to browsers.